# CXF AbstractOutDatabindingInterceptor header omitted during certain requests

Tags: java, rest, cxf, jax-rs

I'm currently writing a REST API that uses a CXF interceptor to add certain headers to each request.

The code of this interceptor is:

```
public class TestHeaderInterceptor extends AbstractOutDatabindingInterceptor {

    public TestHeaderInterceptor() {
        super(Phase.SEND);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message message) {
        MultivaluedMap<String, Object> headers = (MetadataMap<String, Object>) message.get(Message.PROTOCOL_HEADERS);
        if (headers == null) {
            headers = new MetadataMap<String, Object>();
        }
        headers.add("X-Test", "test");
        message.put(Message.PROTOCOL_HEADERS, headers);
    }
}
```

So, as you can see I'm adding a header called `X-Test` with value `test`. When I use a CXF REST client (proxy based), I'm using the following code to add the interceptor to the client:

```
Client client = WebClient.client(clientObj);
ClientConfiguration config = WebClient.getConfig(client);
List<Interceptor<? extends Message>> interceptors = new ArrayList<Interceptor<? extends Message>>();
interceptors.add(new TestHeaderInterceptor());
config.setOutInterceptors(interceptors);
```

My REST API only has 2 actions:

```
@GET
@Produces(JSON_UTF8)
@Path("test/{id}")
Test test(@PathParam("id") String id);


@POST
@Produces(JSON_UTF8)
@Path("test2/{type}")
@Consumes(JSON_UTF8)
Test test2(Test obj, @PathParam("type") Type type);
```

The `test/{id}` method works successfully and it adds the header (checked with Wireshark). However, the `test2/{type}` call does not add the header to the request.

The weirdest thing is that, while using debug, the interceptor code is clearly invoked, which leaves me to think that somehow Apache CXF is ommitting the headers I add.

That's also the reason why I'm using the `Phase.SEND` phase in stead of `Phase.MARSHALL`, just because  I thought my headers are ommitted somewhere in the process of running through all these phases. But even now the headers are still missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some debugging I found out that the CXF interceptor chain is different when I'm using the `test2` call, for example:

### Interceptor chain with test:

```
[2014-06-13 10:49:48,535] - [DEBUG] - [Default Executor-thread-1] - [PhaseInterceptorChain.java:682] - Chain org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain@1384d8d1 was modified. Current flow:
  pre-logical [ClientRequestFilterInterceptor]
  prepare-send [MessageSenderInterceptor]
  marshal [TestHeaderInterceptor]
  prepare-send-ending [MessageSenderEndingInterceptor]
```

### Interceptor chain with test2:

```
[2014-06-13 10:50:02,205] - [DEBUG] - [Default Executor-thread-1] - [PhaseInterceptorChain.java:682] - Chain org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain@69a33de5 was modified. Current flow:
  pre-logical [ClientRequestFilterInterceptor]
  prepare-send [MessageSenderInterceptor]
  write [BodyWriter]
  marshal [TestHeaderInterceptor]
  prepare-send-ending [MessageSenderEndingInterceptor]
```

As you can see there is an additional `BodyWriter` interceptor at the **WRITE** phase. I suppose that when writing the request body, you can no longer access the headers (because the body comes after the headers).

So, the fix was to actually move the `TestHeaderInterceptor` to a phase before the `BodyWriter`, so in my code I'm now using the following code in my constructor:

```
public TestHeaderInterceptor() {
    super(Phase.SETUP);
}
```